# Modelling research paper data in JSON

Tags: algorithms, javascript, programming-practices, data-structures, performance

I need to design an UI to edit a research paper, I don't have enough knowledge about the research domain but still I tried to do my best and thought to design a normalized schema. I am describing the requirement below.

**Sample paper format:**

Below paper showing `4` authors affiliating `3` different organizations.

> Decoupling Sensor Networks from Rasterization in Congestion Control
>
> Alice Abaraham<sup>1</sup> Bill Byron<sup>2</sup> Christie Chang<sup>1, 2</sup> David Doel<sup>3</sup>
>
> 1 University of Utopia
>
> 2 Neverland Institute of Technology
>
> 3 University of Argleton

**The page should allow user to:**

1. Enter the title
2. Add the author
3. Add the affiliation
4. Associate author with their corresponding affiliation
5. Reorder authors
6. Delete author
7. Save the current information

The paper may or may not have author, each author may or may not have affiliation.

**Now the confusing part:**

Affiliations have to be numbered automatically, starting `1` for the first author and so on. Reordering the author should renumber affiliations as well. Each affiliation must have an author associated with it.

The save operation must persist the JSON.

My normalized data:

```
  entities: {
    authors: {
      byId: {
        1: {id: 1, name: "Alice Abaraham"},
        2: {id: 2, name: "Bill Byron"},
        3: {id: 3, name: "Christie Chang"},
        4: {id: 4, name: "David Doel"}
      },
      allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    organizations: {
      byId: {
        1: {id: 1, name: "University of Utopia"},
        2: {id: 2, name: "Neverland Institute of Technology"},
        3: {id: 3, name: "University of Argleton"}
      },
      allIds: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    authorOrganization: {
      byId: {
        1: {id: 1, authorId: 1, organizationId: 1}
        2: {id: 2, authorId: 2, organizationId: 2}
        3: {id: 3, authorId: 3, organizationId: 1}
        4: {id: 4, authorId: 3, organizationId: 2}
        5: {id: 5, authorId: 4, organizationId: 3}
      },
      allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
    papers: {
      byId: {
        1: {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Paper title',
          authors: [1, 2, 3, 4],
          affiliations: {
            byId: {
              1: {id: 1, authorId: 1, organizationIds: [1]},
              2: {id: 2, authorId: 2, organizationIds: [2]},
              3: {id: 3, authorId: 3, organizationIds: [1, 2]},
              4: {id: 4, authorId: 4, organizationIds: [3]}
            },
            allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4]
          }
        }
      },
      allIds: [1]
    }
  }
```

**Update 1:**

Normalizing state shape is inspired from [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html)

**Update 2:**

I find that many people are confused, from understanding `author` and `organization` are related via m2m relation and affiliation is something specific to a paper.

**Questions:**

1. Is the representation correct for the problem statement above?
2. The given representation would scale for millions of thousands of authors?
3. Reordering the author should renumber affiliations as well, how?

Comment: Did you consider using some software (perhaps some web application) related to [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) ?

Comment: It doesn't seem very DRY. Why not something like `{ "organisations": { "id": 1, "name": "Unseen University" }, "authors": { "id": 1, "name": "Ridcully", "affiliations": [1] }, "papers": [{ "id": 1, "title": "What is the colour of magic?", "authors": [1] }] }`. The organisation ID in the data doesn't have to be the one displayed; generating the ordinals in author order can be done at rendering time. Why store `allIds` when that's just the keys of `byId`?

Comment: Question 0 should be "Would this application be better served by storing the data using something designed to represent normalized data, such as SQLite?"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Its programming task and hence I have to build it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For items with some ordering, you use an array. Not a dictionary with keys 1 to n.

You don't store redundant data. allIDs: [1, 2, 3, 4] is redundant. It is either easily deducted from the available data, in which case it is pointless, or it is incorrect, in which case it is worth than pointless. No redundant data in your JSON. So that part should be:

```
authors: [
    {id: 1, name: "Alice Abaraham"},
    {id: 2, name: "Bill Byron"},
    {id: 3, name: "Christie Chang"},
    {id: 4, name: "David Doel"}
  ],
```

"authorOrganization" and "affiliations" seem to be the same. So one of them should go. Actually, I'd just store the organisation IDs with the authors. So

```
authors: [
    {id: 1, name: "Alice Abaraham", organisations: [1] },
    {id: 2, name: "Bill Byron", organisations: [2] },
    {id: 3, name: "Christie Chang", organisations: [1, 2] },
    {id: 4, name: "David Doel", organisations: [3] }
  ],
```

Then the organisations:

```
organizations: [
    {id: 1, name: "University of Utopia"},
    {id: 2, name: "Neverland Institute of Technology"},
    {id: 3, name: "University of Argleton"}
],
```

authorOrganization isn't needed at all, and papers becomes

```
papers: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Paper title',
      authors: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
]
```

Remember that JSON is a format for information interchange, not a database. Which means all the information has to be loaded into memory. "Millions of authors"? On a decent desktop computer, yes. On a mobile device, no. Since it's not a database, there can be only one user at a time. One user maintaining "millions of authors"? No, that doesn't scale.

And make sure you know what the role of an "id" is. Items have ids, which are assigned once, and which then never, ever change. For example, "Bill Byron" will keep that ID, even after you fix the spelling to "Bill Brian", then to "William Brian jr.", then to "Dr. William Brian jr.", then after he gets married to "Dr. William Brian-Jones". The id will always be "2".

Comment: Affiliation is per paper basis, I don't see affiliation in your paper. Also, if you follow the link for normalized data you get to know why I used IDs.